# Entity Framework - Entity read-only property mapped to a column of related table

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-database-first

I have interesting problem to solve but, although common, it looks like it's not easily achievable with Entity Framework. There are two tables:

```
Player(Id,TeamId,FirstName,LastName)
Team(Id, Name, IsProfessional)
```

Player can belong only to one team. Using TPT (DB first), we have two classes mapped to those tables:

```
public class Player
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public int TeamId{get;set;}
   public string FirstName{get; set;}
   public string LastName{get; set;}
   public Team Team{get;set;}
}

public class Team
{ 
   public int Id{get; set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public bool IsProfessional{get;set;}
   public IEnumerable<Player> Players{get;}
}
```

What I would like to achieve is property IsProfessional on Player entity:

```
public class Player
    {
       public int Id{get;set;}
       public int TeamId{get;set;}
       public string FirstName{get; set;}
       public string LastName{get; set;}
       public Team Team{get;set;}
       **public bool IsProfessional{get;}** should be read-only
    }
```

Is it possible to configure mapping that way IsProfessional property can be used in linq queries?

```
var result= db.Players.Where(p=>p.IsProfessional==true);
```

and to have that field populated every time Player entity is materialized?

```
Player pl = db.Players.Where(p=>p.FirstName="Lionel").FirstOrDefault();
if(pl.IsProfessional)
{
//do something...
}
```

Already tried with:

- **Entity Splitting**. Not possible because I want to keep Team mapping and because relationship is not 1:1)
- **Mapping Player entity to a db view**. Didn't like it because there are other relationships Player entity has that I need. I know it is possible to create them manually, but updating edmx from database will reset ssdl.

Thanks

**Solution**

Based on second option in Gert Arnold answer, solution that fits my needs is as follows:

1. I create function `GetIsProfessional` (had to do it because computed fields normally can be made only from own table fields)

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetIsProfessional](@teamId as INT)
   RETURNS bit

   BEGIN

   DECLARE @isProfi AS bit

   SELECT @isProfi = IsProfessional
   FROM Teams
   WHERE Id = @teamId

   RETURN @isProfi

   END
   ```
2. I created computed field on `Player` table

   ```
   ALTER TABLE Players ADD [IsProfessional] AS dbo.GetIsProfessional(TeamId)
   ```
3. As I'm using db first approach, I just update model from database and that's it, I can query on that field and it's pre populated when Player object is materialized.

Comment: So `Player.IsProfessional` should give the same result as `Player.Team.IsProfessional`? EF doesn't currently support properties that don't map to a simple database field, sorry, but perhaps someone will answer with a good alternative.

Comment: That's exactly what I need, except Player.IsProfessional should be read only. All alternatives I could find myself are not realy nice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can't be done with EF. There are some options that don't do exactly what you want, but get close more or less:

1. Create a property `TeamPlayers` in your context that returns the players with the team included, so that you can always do `player.Team.IsProfessional` even when the context has already been diposed.

   ```
   public IQueryable<Player> TeamPlayers
   {
       get { return this.Players.Include("Team"); }
   }
   ```
2. Create a calculated field in the database table and map to it with `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed`.
3. Create a static property in `Player` that returns the expression that accesses `Team.IsProfessional` (requires a living context or team included):

   ```
   public static Expression<Func<Player, bool>> IsProfessional
   {
       get { return p => p.Team.IsProfessional; }
   }
   ...
   db.Players.Where( p=> p.FirstName="Lionel").Where(Player.IsProfessional)....
   ```

I would prefer the calculated field, because it is always populated, so you can use it inside and outside the scope of a context.

Comment: Great! Calculated field fits my needs the best: 1) I can query on computed field, 2) it is populated with other Player properties. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

What if you extend Player to have a property that pulls from Team?

```
public partial class Player
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public int TeamId{get;set;}
   public string FirstName{get; set;}
   public string LastName{get; set;}
   public Team Team{get;set;}

   public bool IsProfessional{ get { return Team.IsProfessional; } }
}
```

Of course, if you're worried about regenerating your EDMX, you can make it a partial:

```
public partial class Player
{
   public bool IsProfessional{ get { return Team.IsProfessional; } }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this way Player.IsProfessional is not usable in linq queries (as I explained in question). Also, when property  Player.IsProfessional is accessed it will do sql query just to get one boolean from db. I would prefer if that boolean is filled at same time as all other Player properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [***`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMappedAttribute`***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute.aspx) to prevent mapping of the ***`IsProfessional`*** property like these:

```
// Mapped part of entity
public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }
}

// Unmapped part of entity
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
...
public partial class Player
{
    [NotMapped()]
    public bool IsProfessional { get { /* ... IsProfessional calculation logic comes here ... */ } }
}
```

I used this attribute in ***`EF5's Model First`*** approach and I queried over ***`DbContext/DbSet`*** and ***`ObjectContext/ObjectQuery`*** without any exceptions. (100% tested)

Comment: OK, but this property doesn't show in the DataSource I create from this  entity.

Comment: I usually use ObjectDataSource and it show all public properties of my entity classes.
I think EntityDataSource just read mapped properties of generated entities because of their schema declaration in .edmx file.

Comment: Does this work? What about the Linq problems stated above

Comment: It is good enough to provide a calculated (virtual) data column along with Eager Loading approach, but there is no way to translate its logic to real data column(s) in WHERE clause of custom query.