# Decorating EF Code First models with methods that need access to the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I have a EF model class `Comment` with a navigation property `ScoreVotes` referencing `ScoreVote` which has member `int Score`. In `Comment` I have the following method `Score()`:

```
    public int Score()
    {
        var votes = this.ScoreVotes;

        if (votes == null)
            return 0;
        else
        {
            int score = 0;

            foreach (var scoreVote in votes)
            {
                score += scoreVote.Score;
            }

            return score;
        }
    }
```

I have the following questions:

1. How can I tell EF to bring over the `Comment`'s `ScoreVotes` up-front if I know that I will need to calculate the score? (Should I use `Include`?)
2. If I made `Score` a property whose getter method matched the current method, would `Score` be recorded in the database? Would it always reflect the last calculated score?

Answer (score 0):

Create the column Score in the Table Comment. And just update the Score column when you add/update/delete the ScoreVotes related to the Comment.

There's also the use of calculated fields.

Here are more options. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12817314/181766